# The type or namespace name 'ViewModels' does not exist in the namespace 'myMVCApplication' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to develop the Mvc application, but
I always get the message I mention in my subject when try to run it.

here is the content of view that refer to it.

```
@model myMVCApplication.ViewModels.FormData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Tanggal</th>
    <th>Satelit</th>
    <th>Pembicara</th>
    <th>Worship Manager</th>
  </tr>

@{DateTime LastDate = @DateTime.Now.Date;}
@foreach (var f in Model.Forms)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
       <span>
          @if (LastDate != f.Tanggal)
          {
             LastDate = @f.Tanggal;
             @String.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy}", f.Tanggal)<br />
          }
       </span>
    </td>

    <td>

        @if (f.satelite != null)
        {
            @f.satelite.SateliteName;
        }
     </td>

    <td>@f.Pembicara;</td>
    <td>@f.WorshipManager</td>
  </tr>    
}
</table>
```

and here is the content of FormData class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using myMVCApplication.Models;

namespace myMVCApplication.ViewModels
{
    public class FormData
    {
        public IEnumerable<Form> Forms { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Satelite> Satelites { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have tried to search the solution for this, and found several links including from stackoverflow, but nothing can solve my problem.
If it said no assembly reference to the ViewModels, it is already in my application.
I have check the spell and everything is ok.
Could you please, give me a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this FormData class defined in the ASP.NET MVC project or did you put it in a separate class library in the solution?

Comment: sorry if don't too understand what you mean. What do you mean with defined in ASP.NET MVC project? How to check it? Thanks.

Comment: how many projects do you have in the Visual Studio solution? If you don't understand this maybe you should start with the basics before jumping into ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Are you getting this error in the Visual Studio Errors list, or in your web browser? If in your browser, are you sure you've compiled the project?

Comment: In the web browser. There's no error in Visual Studio. I have Clean the Build, Rebuild, Build with the same result.

Comment: The problem solved, after I changed the build back to any CPU (before it's for x64) it works as it should be. (Note: I change it to x64 because my Dev machine is win7 64, the deployment server is also x64)